# Android read large files crashing app

Tags: java, android, io, md5, java-io

Hello as you can see below I m trying to make a (android) app which check md5 hash of file
this code works only for small files
can someone help me?

```
final TextView informations = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Informations);
            final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ToCrack);
            String filepath = data.getDataString();
            String rawtext;
            String hash;
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            filepath = filepath.split("//")[1];
            File file = new File(filepath);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Loading: "+filepath,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            DataInputStream dis = null;
            try{
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
                while (dis.available() != 0){
                    text.append(dis.readLine()+"\n");
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                try{
                    fis.close();
                    bis.close();
                    dis.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            rawtext = text.toString().substring(0, text.length()-1);
            hash = new MD5(rawtext).hexdigest();
            if (hash.equals(input.getText().toString())){
                informations.setText("Hash correspond with the file!");
            }
            else{
                informations.setText("File hash= "+hash+"\nHashes does not correspond :(");
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Copied file hash to clipboard.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the file in a background thread using AsyncTask?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I didn't tried but this code crash the app directly so I guess it wont work

Comment: edit your question and include the stacktrace.

Comment: Remove the `available()` test. Your code will work the same with `while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)`. There are very few correct uses of `available()`, and this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile device environments such as Android have limitations w.r.t the amount of memory that can be consumed by an application. Hence, reading large files to an in-memory data store as done in your code (using `StringBuffer`) is going to throw an OutOfMemory error.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2214259/1321873) to know how you can overcome the problem.

Comment: I found that funny because using python sl4a on android I m able to calculate md5 and stuff very easily and fast without any crash, google spend more time to make api for ui and stuff and not to simplify 'background' of app like just open a file...

Comment: I am not familiar with sl4a, guess it runs in a native application process. I'd like to point out that each of the apps written in the SDK (not the NDK), runs in it's own Dalvik VM.